# Significado y uso de "tuercebotas"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

He oído esta palabra aparentemente con un significado despectivo, aunque esta acepción peyorativa no la encuentro en el DRAE.

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/tuercebotas) la define como

> *com. amer.*  Persona sin importancia, pelanas.

y en un [foro](http://hispanismo.org/politica-y-sociedad/13338-zapatero-o-tuercebotas.html) he encontrado que

> También se denomina así al jugador de fútbol que destaca por ser un estorbo para su equipo.

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tuercebotas&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctuercebotas%3B%2Cc0) no la recoge hasta 1965, aumentando su uso hasta el año 2000, sin embargo, su frecuencia y utilización desde entonces hasta el día de hoy ha ido en continuo descenso.

¿Se utiliza habitualmente "tuercebotas" como expresión?. ¿Con cuál de los dos significados?. ¿Qué origen tiene?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo siempre había visto esta palabra como un insulto en el ámbito del fútbol.

Pero he encontrado este artículo en el que indagan sobre su origen, con nuevas acepciones:
http://www.abc.es/cultura/20150126/abci-tuercebotas-origen-insulto-201501202037.html

> **Su historia data como mínimo del siglo XIII** y hacía alusión al «rastrapaja referido al palurdo, que se arrastra, y a la persona miserable que a la pobreza material une la espiritual». [...] «es voz creativa que tiene ante si la imagen del vagabundo o pordiosero que anda con los pies medio desnudos, asomando sus dedos por los agujeros de las botas torcidas de andar de un sitio a otro».

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Puedes mejorar tu respuesta si, además del enlace (que está muy bien), copias aquí la parte pertinente del artículo para no tener que acceder a él (o por si el contenido del enlace cambia). De este modo, el enlace queda sólo para efectos de comprobar la información o por si se desea profundizar más.

Comment: Muchas gracias @CarlosAlejo, lo tendré en cuenta para futuras aportaciones.

Answer (score 2):

El uso es el que has dicho, y se utiliza bastante en fútbol de forma despectiva. La procedencia es esta:

Su historia data como mínimo del siglo XIII y hacía alusión a

> El rastrapaja referido al palurdo, que se arrastra, y a la persona
>   miserable que a la pobreza material une la espiritual.

Celdrán habla de la escasa carga ofensiva del término y describe el porqué del curioso nombre

> Es voz creativa que tiene ante si la imagen del vagabundo o pordiosero que anda con los pies medio desnudos, asomando sus dedos por los agujeros de las botas torcidas de andar de un sitio a otro.

**El gran libro de los insultos**

Answer (score 2):

Tuercebotas también se usaba en el ámbito militar para referirse al recluta que no sabía desfilar ni marcar el paso. En otras palabras, alguien que no sabe ni andar recto, porque al pisar mal, sin centrar el peso de la pisada en el centro de la suela, la bota se le tuerce y no es la suela la que contacta con el suelo sino el lateral de la bota. El resultado visual se parece a andar como un pato.
El "insulto" es que si no dominas ni el arte básico de andar, cómo vas a desempeñar otras tareas más complicadas.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que los hablantes, al no entender bien el término, lo asociaran con el lenguaje futbolístico o el militar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24563)