# ¿Por qué "mastuerzo" adquirió el significado de "majadero"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Pensando en ["**tuercebotas**"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18065/significado-y-uso-de-tuercebotas) se me ocurrió que podría tener alguna relación con "**mastuerzo**" (por el "*torcer*" que parecen tener en común).

Sin embargo, el DRAE define [**mastuerzo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OZZoWsq) como

> De *nastuerzo*.
>   1. m. Planta herbácea anual, hortense, de la familia de las crucíferas, con tallo de 30 a 60 cm de altura, hojas inferiores recortadas, y lineales las superiores, con flores blancas y fruto seco capsular con dos semillas. Vive en España, América del Norte y América Central, es comestible y tiene usos en medicina tradicional.
>   2. m. berro.
>   3. m. **majadero** (‖ hombre necio y porfiado). U. t. c. adj.

y [**nastuerzo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QHJpuUm) como

> Del lat. *nasturtium*.
>   1. m. **mastuerzo** (‖ planta crucífera).

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastuerzo) recoge únicamente plantas (y el nombre artístico de un músico).

Luego parece que "mastuerzo" se refiere a plantas crucíferas y ha adquirido (secundariamente) la acepción de "majadero", lo que me lleva a la pregunta que planteo: ¿cómo adquirió el significado de "majadero" (que creo que es el más utilizado de los tres)?

Comment: En [asturiano](http://www.xuliocs.com/etimologlexiclp.htm) _mastuerzo_ significa 'atontado, bruto, tonto, inútil'. Según esa fuente, "por la debilidad de unas cañas blandas, siempre entre el agua, poco resistentes, con frecuencia aplastadas sobre el suelo" (las cañas del del nastuerzo). ¿Habrá alguna relación con "necio y porfiado"?

Comment: @rodrigo Otro significado que tiene en asturiano es «ensin valor, ensin importancia [una cosa]» (D.A.Ll.A.) (*ensin* quiere decir *sin* en castellano).  No parece existir ningún equivalente en portugués, gallego ni catalán, pero en aragonés significa «Persona corta de mente». Veo una posible relación — todas son cualidades negativas — pero tampoco hay mucha semejanza más allá de la negatividad.

Comment: En México, la frase "dar mastuerzo" se utiliza coloquialmente para indicar que a alguien se le dio muerte. Nunca en mi larga vida, y no rechazo las explicaciones dadas anteriormente y mucho menos la acepción <nasturtium> que nos lleva a la etimología de la palabra. Solo me apego al uso vulgar en el que la palabra mastuerzo va forzosamente acompañada de "dar mastuerzo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedo dar una respuesta exacta, pero esta pregunta es de las que me gustan, así que no puedo dejar de comentar lo que he descubierto.

Rastreando el término en el [Nuevo Tesoro Lexicográfico](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico), se puede comprobar que la primera edición del diccionario de la RAE en la que aparece la acepción es la de 1852, en la que se dice que significa

> necio, torpe, majadero

Por su parte, [buscando por Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mastuerzo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmastuerzo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmastuerzo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMastuerzo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMASTUERZO%3B%2Cc0) he encontrado un texto, "El Aljibe de la gitana", de 1872, en el que se puede leer que

> [...] todos los que conocen bien el español, saben que la palabra mastuerzo, es una calificación vulgar equivalente a esta otra: alma de cántaro.

La única pista que he encontrado sobre el posible origen del calificativo está en el [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1996/diccionario-de-autoridades), que en su tomo IV de 1734 se pone como ejemplo de uso de la palabra mastuerzo esta frase:

> El mastuerzo enciende mucho, y da dolor de cabeza.

Por tanto, lo más probable es que en algún momento se empezara a comparar a determinado tipo de personas con los efectos que produce el mastuerzo, del tipo "Fulano es tan necio que me provoca el mismo dolor de cabeza que el mastuerzo". Pero esto último ya es una suposición mía, no he podido encontrar ningún documento escrito al respecto.

Otra posibilidad es que mientras buscaba por Ngram vi algunos tratados de botánica y de huertas que dicen que el cultivo del mastuerzo es fácil. Así pues, es posible que la planta del mastuerzo se encontrara con facilidad en el campo y que tenga una cierta terquedad en aferrarse a la vida, de lo que se podría también establecer la relación con el insulto (por lo de "porfiado", que significa "terco y obstinado").

Comment: ¡Exhaustiva búsqueda! Pero la propia definición del DRAE de 1852 indica que "sus hojas tienen un gusto picante y **agradable**", lo que parece ir en contra de tu hipótesis.

Comment: @user13560 no necesariamente. Las hojas pueden tener ese gusto picante y agradable, y producir dolor de cabeza si se consume en exceso o de forma equivocada. En todo caso, entiendo que mi suposición está algo cogida por los pelos, pero es la única que encontré y no quería dejar de comentarla. No busco ni mucho menos que esta respuesta sea la aceptada como correcta.

Comment: Por cierto (ya lo habrán visto en Wikipedia) la palabra _mastuerzo_ deriva del latín _nasus tortus_, "nariz torcida" por el olor desagradable de la planta. [Aquí está más detallado](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?mastuerzo).

Answer (score 3):

Sabemos que la palabra `mastuerzo` o `mestuerzo` o `nastuerzo` proviene del latín *nasturtium* o *nasturcium*, que significa "nariz torcida".

El por qué de este significado es materia de debate. Hay quien dice que se debe a algún rasgo de la planta, mientras que otros mencionan un supuesto gesto de fruncir la nariz al probar esta planta, presuntamente, debido a su sabor acre.

Esta última explicación parece cuestionable si se trata del berro (otro nombre del mastuerzo), dado que en modo alguno tiene sabor acre sino más bien suave y agradable. Es dable entonces preguntarse si lo del sabor acre podría eventualmente provenir de OTRA especie conocida también como mastuerzo, denominación vulgar que abarca alrededor de cinco especies distintas con sus respectivos nombres científicos. El griego Dioscórides (c.40-c.90) trae en su diccionario de especies botánicas cinco denominaciones griegas diferentes para mastuerzo.

Eventualmente, vaya uno a saber si quienes denominaron a esta planta en latín no estaban haciendo una broma entre ellos.

Cualquiera sea el origen de la frase "nariz torcida" parece claro que se trata de un GESTO DE DESAGRADO, tal vez, el mismo que se siente ante una persona necia, majadera o porfiada. (De paso, en Argentina, por ejemplo, la palabra mastuerzo, de por sí raramente utilizada, ni remotamente tiene la connotación de "necio").

Ahora bien, parecería difícil vincular la palabra MASTUERZO para referirse a una persona necia ya que en el habla vulgar castellana se ha perdido la noción de la etimología "nariz torcida", y de su significación de gesto de desagrado. (Del mismo modo se ha perdido la noción de que murciélago significa ratón cegezuelo).

Una posibilidad es que quien por primera vez haya usado en castellano el término mastuerzo para aludir a una persona necia, hubiese tenido algún conocimiento del significado etimológico, sea que fuera un profesor de latín, un botánico, un farmacéutico, o cualquier hijo de vecino que hubiera venido a enterarse de ese significado.